# Merge [barcode-scanner] and [barcode-printing] into [barcode]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Is there any reason for [barcode-scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/barcode-scanner) and [barcode-printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/barcode-printing) when we have [barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/barcode)?

Comment: We have [tag:input] and [tag:output] when we have [tag:io]

Comment: Something tells me these tags are full of off topic questions